# Fixed refresh at top, refresh controllers routes on

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following HTML structure  but I want my refresh button to refresh whatever is current in the view. The view builds different stuff depending on its route. Is this possible to achieve in Angular?

```
<header>
    <refresh button />
</header>

<ng-view></ng-view>

<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$route.reload` method. Consider this demo:

HTML:

```
<header>
    <button ng-click="refresh()">Refresh</button>
</header>
```

And you define refresh function in the scope:

```
$scope.refresh = function() {
    $route.reload();
};
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/mhhxmRacNIuET4u74Aty?p=preview

Comment: Thank you! you are the absolute greatest. Was on this for awhile now